# Monitored Undo Framework with observablecollection in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, observablecollection, undo-redo

My UI project is a usercontrol, which is loaded later on an other app.

I would like to implement an undo/redo system so I'm trying to do this with MUF (Monitored Undo Framework). I'm testing on sliders for the moment, bound to an observablecollection :

```
private ObservableCollection<double> _ChannelsAlpha = new ObservableCollection<double>(new[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 });
public ObservableCollection<double> ChannelsAlpha
{
    get { return _ChannelsAlpha; }
    set
    { //_ChannelsAlpha = value;
        if (value == _ChannelsAlpha)
            return;
        DefaultChangeFactory.OnChanging(this, "ChannelsAlpha", _ChannelsAlpha, value, "ChannelsAlpha Changed");
        _ChannelsAlpha = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ChannelsAlpha"); // Tells the UI that this property has changed.
    }
}
```

My commandbinding for the usercontrol :

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Undo" Executed="Undo_Executed" CanExecute="Undo_CanExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="Redo" Executed="Redo_Executed" CanExecute="Redo_CanExecute" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Undo function look like this :

```
private void Undo_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var undoRoot = UndoService.Current[this];
    undoRoot.Undo();
}
```

I followed the documentation's example on [MUF](http://muf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WpfUndoSample/MainWindow.xaml.cs), the code is quite long so I didn't copy/paste everything here. But I could do it if needed.

I think the command in XAML is not doing anything but as I'm beginner, I'm not sure. Any hint ? 
Thank you